# How do I generate sharp images Cifar-10

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow

I'm working with tensorflow and trying to visualize the input/output of an autoencoder on Cifar-10.

I'm following this answer here: [Why CIFAR-10 images are not displayed properly using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995999/why-cifar-10-images-are-not-displayed-properly-using-matplotlib/40144107#40144107)

Here's the result from running their code with slight modification (change the figsize to 5,5):

[image: Visualized Images]

However, this is still nowhere as sharp and clear as the images in the original page: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

How can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two issues here:

**Issue 1:**

It looks like your color channels (red, green, blue) are mixed. That would explain why the colors are so weird. If that is the case you will need to swap the color channels in your array as I have shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data

rgb_image = plt.imread(get_sample_data("grace_hopper.png", asfileobj=False))

# correct color channels (R, G, B)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image: natural color]

```
# swapped color channels (R, B, G)
rgb_image = rgb_image[:, :, [0, 2, 1]]
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image: swapped color channels]

**Issue 2:**

Matplotlib's `plt.imshow` has a keyword argument `interpolation` which defaults to `None` if not specified. Matplotlib then refers to the your local style sheet to determine the default interpolation behavior. Depending on your style sheet, this may result in interpolation being applied and therefore distortion of your image. See the [documentation for imshow for more details](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).

If you want to guarantee that Matplotlib does not interpolate your image, you should specify `interpolation="none"` in `plt.imshow`. This is confusing because the default NoneType value of `None` yields different behavior than the string value of `"none"`.

```
red = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
red[:, :, 0] = 255
red[40:60, 40:60, :] = 255

# with interpolation
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(red, interpolation='bicubic') 
plt.axis('off')
```

[image: with interpolation]

```
# without interpolation
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(red, interpolation='none') 
plt.axis('off')
```

[image: without interpolation]

Comment: With Matplotlib 2.0 the default interpolation has changed to `'image.interpolation': 'nearest'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do something like this. The images are very small, of the size of 32px in height and width, hence the they will be sharper only when in the size of thumbnails. I have interpolated it using bicubic transformation here. But you can change it to 'none' so that instead of blurry, you will get a pixelated image.

```
def unpickle(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict1 = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict1

pd_tr = pd.DataFrame()
tr_y = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,6):
    data = unpickle('data/data_batch_' + str(i))
    pd_tr = pd_tr.append(pd.DataFrame(data[b'data']))
    tr_y = tr_y.append(pd.DataFrame(data[b'labels']))
    pd_tr['labels'] = tr_y

tr_x = np.asarray(pd_tr.iloc[:, :3072])
tr_y = np.asarray(pd_tr['labels'])
ts_x = np.asarray(unpickle('data/test_batch')[b'data'])
ts_y = np.asarray(unpickle('data/test_batch')[b'labels'])    
labels = unpickle('data/batches.meta')[b'label_names']

def plot_CIFAR(ind):
    arr = tr_x[ind]
    R = arr[0:1024].reshape(32,32)/255.0
    G = arr[1024:2048].reshape(32,32)/255.0
    B = arr[2048:].reshape(32,32)/255.0

    img = np.dstack((R,G,B))
    title = re.sub('[!@#$b]', '', str(labels[tr_y[ind]]))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img,interpolation='bicubic')
    ax.set_title('Category = '+ title,fontsize =15)

plot_CIFAR(4)
```